# How to make S3 buckets appear in the list of cloudfront origin of another Aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a requirement in which I have cloudfront distribution in staging Aws account and S3 buckets in production account. How can I make production buckets appear in the list of origin domain in staging account?

Comment: Can you just refer to the bucket name, rather than choosing it from a list? [Using Amazon S3 Origins, MediaPackage Channels, and Custom Origins for Web Distributions - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes i did that but the requirement of my client is to list out s3 buckets of production in staging account origin list at any cost. Is it possible anyhow?

Comment: List it within the CloudFront management console? No, that is not possible.